# if table1 field1 matches table2 field2 echo table1 field2

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently learning MYSQL and php and hoping for some advice on table joins. I have 2 tables:

**table1**

```
model_name
quantity
```

**table2**

```
model_name
customer_name
```

I need to echo customer_name underneath the model if the model of table 2 matches table1 model_name

Here is what i have at the moment

```
$sql = "SELECT id, model_name, quantity FROM model";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
echo "<table width='100%' style='margin:15px;'><tr>";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<td> " . $row["model_name"] . "<br />" . $row["quantity"] . "</td>";
}

echo "</tr><tr>";

echo "</tr></table>";
```

I appreciate any advice you could offer.

Comment: Left join table 2 to table 1? What is the relation between table 2 model and 1 model_name?

Comment: update your question    add   a proper data sample and the expected  resutl

Comment: You need to `JOIN` your two tables together in your SQL statement and return what you like from that relationship. Can't help more than that though since it's not at all obvious what the relationship between the two tables is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t2.customer_name 
FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN table1 t1
ON t1.model_name=t2.model
```

Comment: I was able to modify it a bit but it worked in the end, thanks! :D